# How can I use a macro to create a new excel spreadsheet with values only and formatting (including results of conditional formatting)

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I have written this macro to unprotect an existing worksheet, copy the data from the existing worksheet, open a new spreadsheet, paste the data to the new spreadsheet with values and formatting, then protect the existing worksheet again.

The issue is that the result of the conditional formatting is not pasted, only the base formatting. I would like to know how to retain the formats resulting the CF rules in the new spreadsheet. Any help here would be appreciated - thanks.

```
Sub Create_Monthly_Return()

'Unprotect

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Monthly Return").Unprotect Password:="password"
    
'Create new spreadsheet  
Columns("A:N").Select
    
Selection.Copy

Workbooks.Add
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
        xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    
'Protect
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Monthly Return").Protect Password:="password"

End Sub
```

Comment: Your problem is not clear. You unprotect the "Monthly Return" sheet,, but copy the active sheet, which need not to be the same. Was that your intention?

Comment: Generally the code copies conditonal formatting as well as the base one. I tried only simple rules. Maybe the problem is with conditional formatting rules?

Comment: do you want to copy the formatting (including the rules for conditional formatting), or do you want to copy the current format (including the *result* of those rules at the time)?

Comment: The macro works for the most part. The only part not working is that I want the formatting that results from the CF to be copied to the new spreadsheet not the conditional formatting rules.